# Origin and position difference

Tags: position, libgdx

I'm learning the libgdx engine and i got difficulties understanding the difference of .setOrigin and .setPosition . Take the demo libgdx creates. What is the difference if i put 1f,1f on origin and what on position of the texture this demo uses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Origin is used for **Scaling** and **Rotating** transforms. For example, if you put the origin at the Center of your sprite (`width/2, height/2`). When you rotate it, it will rotate around its center.

The position is the `bottom-left` corner of your sprite in world coordinates.

> What is the difference if i put 1f,1f on origin and what on position of the texture this demo uses?

On origin it won't make any difference if you don't rotate or scale the sprite. On position, it will change where the sprite is drawn.

Comment: Does this mean that if i set the origin on its center and then change the position It will move relative to its center or it will still place it according it's bottom left corner?

Comment: The origin only affects rotation and scaling. So, no. setting position is always according to its bottom left corner. @j0hnskot

Comment: @jühnskot be careful when setting the origin. It is relative to the position. If you set a wrong origin and rotate your sprite some strange things can happen (my character "rotated" out of screen xD)